GnuCobol file not found
I am looking for a solution for the following problem.
I run a very simple cobol program to read a file.
I use the following code :
 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.      
   PROGRAM-ID. GADGETS.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
   SELECT Gadgetfile ASSIGN TO "STOCK.DAT"
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD Gadgetfile.

The file stock.dat exist in the same directory of the program.
I get the following error :
libcob: error: file does not exist (status = 35) for file Gadgetfile ('STOCK_DAT' => STOCK.DAT)
If I use simple quote of double quote nothing change.
This means that the program can't find the file.
I use Gnucobol running on Redat 9.4 the same problem occur on fedora 40.
I think that I need to use some export of something related to DD ?
Help will be appreciated
Kind regards.

How are you running the app?  Remember that names are case sensitive, so "stock.dat" is not the same as "STOCK.DAT".  Also remember that it will start looking in the "current directory", not in the directory that contains the app.

Thank you for your reaction. Cobol is not case senssitive. The app run in the same directory.

Just because the LANGUAGE is case-insensitive does not mean that file names are!  The app is bound by whatever the operating system does.

As you run on GNU/Linux, you will very likely run the program on a file system that is case-sensitive [1], therefore when you want to read "stock.dat", you also have to ASSIGN TO "stock.dat" (lower case).
The COBOL runtime will search non-absolute filenames in the working directory of the program (not necessarily the place where the program resides). So you either want to start the program from that directory (cd /home/user/languages/cobol_lang && ./gadgets instead of /home/user/languages/cobol_lang/gadgets) or want to setup the file path (for GnuCOBOL's runtime library libcob: COB_FILE_PATH=/home/user/languages/cobol_lang /home/user/languages/cobol_lang/gadgets).
As an alternative you can use file mapping for a single file, in GnuCOBOL that would be (no matter if you use upper- or lowercase in ASSIGN): DD_STOCK_DAT=/home/user/languages/cobol_lang/stock.dat /home/user/languages/cobol_lang/gadgets (you can also drop the DD_ prefix for the environment variable, if there's no environment variable with it, then libcob will check the name without it).

And, as a different option: you can also ASSIGN TO stock-file-name and use MOVE "/home/user/languages/cobol_lang/gadgets/stock.dat" to that (or put it as initial VALUE into a variable with that name).

[1] you may not have case-sensitive file systems on GNU/Linux (when mounting a FAT32 disk for example) and you may have a case-sensitive file system on Windows (even NTFS has that option, it is just uncommon)

Thanks a lot. You point out some documentation that I have to read.

I finally found the solution.
I need to put the full path of the name.
In my case :
    "/home/user/languages/cobol_lang/sto"
-"ck.dat"

On 2 lines because the length of the path is more than 72 char.
The - in column 7 is for the continuation line.
